# Transforming my calculation to an user defined function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to convert my calculation to a UDF, but I keep getting and error and not sure how to correct it.

Here's the code:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_q1 (integer) RETURNS integer stable as $$
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN q_1 IN ('8', '9', '10') THEN RESPONSE_ID END))*1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN q_1 IS NOT NULL THEN RESPONSE_ID END))*1.0
$$ language sql;
```

I'm essentially trying to take the code below:

```sql
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN f.q_1 IN ('8', '9', '10') THEN f.RESPONSE_ID END))*1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN f.q_1 IS NOT NULL THEN f.RESPONSE_ID END))*1.0 AS q_1
FROM FACT f
```

And create it into a UDF that I can call on throughout my query.

This is my first time doing UDFs - could someone help me correct this?

Comment: Can you provide a description of what you'd like the UDF to do **in words**?

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE FUNCTION f_q1 (integer)` says that you are passing in a single integer. Therefore, your UDF can only use that integer to determine its output.

There is nothing called `q_1` in the function, nor are there multiple rows of input. It is a **scalar UDF**, which means that it accepts a certain number of input values and returns a single output value.

You might consider using a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) instead of a Scalar UDF.

But, frankly, if your above query works, just continue to use it. There's no particular benefit to putting it inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Amazon Redshift user defined functions are scalar only. They only accept single value parameters as input and return a single output value.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html

If you wish to encapsulate an aggregation, like `COUNT(DISTINCT )`, then you would need to use a stored procedure instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html

Alternatively you can perform the `COUNT(DISTINCT )` separately and encapsulate the  `CASE` logic in a two UDFs. For example:

```
--Two parameters: q_1 and response_id
CREATE FUNCTION f_key_question(INTEGER,INTEGER) 
RETURNS INTEGER
STABLE AS $$
    SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IN (8,9,10) THEN $2 ELSE NULL END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
;
CREATE FUNCTION f_any_question(INTEGER) 
RETURNS INTEGER
STABLE AS $$
    SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN $2 ELSE NULL END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(f_key_question(f.q_1,f.response_id))::NUMERIC
     / COUNT(DISTINCT(f_any_question(f.q_1,f.response_id))::NUMERIC  AS q_1
FROM fact f
;
```